# Replace numbers string in attribute

Tags: php, replace, attributes, numbers

Have made the following visible on frontend to show the stock in two locations:

```
<?php if($attrValue = $_product->getData('inventory_location_01')): ?>
            <p><?php echo $this->__('Aalborg') ?>: <span><?php echo $attrValue ?> stk.</span></p>
            <?php endif; ?>
<?php if($attrValue = $_product->getData('inventory_location_02')): ?>
            <p><?php echo $this->__('Brønderslev') ?>: <span><?php echo $attrValue ?> stk.</span></p>
            <?php endif; ?>
```

My problem is that the stock is shown as 2.0000 if there are to in stock of the item.

I would like to remove the .0000 after the number 2.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at [`printf`](http://php.net/manual/de/function.printf.php) (or [here](https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_printf.asp)), e.g `<?php printf("%.0f",$attrValue); ?>`

Comment: Could you tell me where to place it in the above code to make it work :)

Comment: Found the solution..
Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

you can make

```
<?php echo str_replace(".0000","",$attrValue) ?>
```

it will remove the .0000 after the number.

Or you can use the function number_format($attrValue)

```
<?php echo number_format($attrValue) ?>
```